# Insert primary key to other tables using VB.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, primary-key, sql-insert

I'm using SQL Server as my DBMS and I have 2 tables namely `Person` and `Voter`.

`Person` has these columns:

- `PersonId` (`int`, primary key auto-increment int_identity),
- `FirstName` (`nvarchar(50)`)
- `LastName` (`nvarchar(50)`)

`Voter` has these columns:

- `VoterPersonId` (`int`, foreign key)
- `VoterPlace` (`nvarchar(50)`)

These 2 tables are related. For 1 person there can only be 1 voter place. So you may call it a one is to one relationship. I created 2 tables because there are also people who aren't voters that I must include in my database and I don't want to create null values so I made a separate table which is the 'voter' table. Basically, I wanted to know the number registered voters and non-voters in our city. Now, I have created a 'save' button in VB.NET and used the following code to insert information into my tables:

```
Dim sql As New SQLControl

Private Sub cmdSave_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click

sql.con.Open()

Using cmdPerson As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Person(FirstName, LastName) VALUES('" & txtFirstName.Text & "', '" & txtLastName.Text & "')", sql.con)
cmdPerson.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using

Using cmdVoter As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Voter(VoterPlace) VALUES('" & txtVoterPlace.Text & "')", sql.con)
cmdVoter.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using

sql.con.Close()

End Sub
```

Now, my problem is I don't know how to transfer the value of 'PersonId' primary key which is auto-increment in_identity into 'VoterPersonId' the moment I click on the 'save' button. Is it possible? Can you please help me on this matter? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute both queries in a single stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertPerson
@firstname varchar(50),
@lastname varchar(50),
@voterPlace varchar(50)
AS
declare @newid int
INSERT INTO Person(Firstname, Lastname) VALUES (@firstname, @lastname)
SELECT @newid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO Voter(VoterPersonId, VoterPlace) VALUES ( @newid, @voterPlace)
```

Comment: I find this answer better after some research.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stored procedure but you certainly don't have to.  The principle is still the same though.  You execute the insert to the parent table and then use the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` function to get the auto-generated ID.  You would then use an output parameter to get that value back into your app so that you can include it in the next insert to the child table, e.g.

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here"),
      parentCommand As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Parent (ParentName) VALUES (@ParentName); SET @ParentId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();", connection),
      childCommand As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Child (ParentId, ChildName) VALUES (@ParentId, @ChildName)", connection)
    With parentCommand.Parameters
        .AddWithValue("@ParentName", parentName)
        .Add("@ParentId", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    End With

    connection.Open()

    Dim transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()

    Try
        parentCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        With childCommand.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("@ParentId", parentCommand.Parameters("@ParentId").Value)
            .AddWithValue("@ChildName", childName)
        End With

        childCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        transaction.Commit()
    Catch
        transaction.Rollback()
    End Try
End Using
```

Comment: It's just example code to demonstrate a principle.  As with all examples, the names used won't necessarily be the same as you would use in your specific situation.  Look at the principle.  Insert a record into a parent table, retrieve the auto-generated ID via `SCOPE_IDENTITY` and an output parameter and then use that value when inserting a record into a child table.  What the tables and columns are actually named and what values you use is completely dependent on your project.

Comment: As for how to use parameters, it's exactly the same here as in any other ADO.NET code.  If you want general information on using parameters in ADO.NET then look for that information as it's not part of this specific problem, e.g. http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html

Comment: Wow, now I'm enlightened! Thank you very much for your help. I learned something new today. There's still so much room for improvement for me. I truly respect programmers and I hope I can be a great coder like you someday and teach other aspiring coders like me.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if it is the best answer to your question.  It helps others who may find this thread by searching to know what to focus on.